How to convert results of simulated t-tests into a dataframe?
I am trying to get better intuition about statistical testing by using simulations in R. I would like to simulate t-test results and explore the variation in estimates, p-values etc. I manage to run the simulation but the output of the simulation seems to be a complicated list and I am not able to coerce the results into a simple data frame (or a tibble). Could anyone help me with that?
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

popul1 <- rnorm(1000, 5, 2)
popul2 <- rnorm(1000, 3, 2)

t.test.fun <- function(size) {
  samp1 <- sample(popul1, size = size, replace = TRUE)
  samp2 <- sample(popul2, size = size, replace = TRUE)
  
  dat <- tibble(group = rep(c("group1", "group2"), each = size),
                value = c(samp1, samp2))
 tidy(t.test(value~group, dat)) 
}
t.test.fun(10)

sims <- replicate(1000, t.test.fun(10), simplify = TRUE)

sims1 <- t(sims) %>% 
  as_tibble()

str(sims1)

ggplot(sims1, aes(p.value)) +
  geom_density()


sims1[] <- lapply(sims1, unlist)


head(sims1)
#   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                  alternative
#      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                   <chr>      
# 1    0.886      4.24      3.35     0.997 0.332        17.9  -0.983       2.75 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
# 2    2.89       6.10      3.22     2.90  0.00968      17.9   0.791       4.98 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
# 3    1.13       4.14      3.02     1.59  0.131        15.5  -0.374       2.62 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
# 4    1.49       5.65      4.16     1.64  0.118        17.7  -0.419       3.40 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
# 5    2.27       5.02      2.75     2.33  0.0321       17.6   0.217       4.31 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
# 6    2.07       5.34      3.27     2.13  0.0472       17.5   0.0289      4.12 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  

